# How do I save a model when using Play Morphia MongodDb plugin?

Tags: scala, mongodb, playframework, morphia

I am using morphia plugin for play framework and my code is in scala.
The documentation of this plugin:

http://www.playframework.org/modules/morphia-1.2.1beta6/home

I could not find any documentation regarding how do I save a model instance in mongodb databse like:

```
val user = new User(cid: "iyoiyoiy97097097")
// how to save now?
```

domain model is:

```
@Entity
class User(@Required val cid: String, val isAdmin: Boolean = false, @Required val dateJoined: DateTime = new DateTime() ) extends Model
```

Is this query correct:

```
val user = User.filter("cid", "123123123sdfsdf").get()
```

Please note that people often confuse Morphia with Play framework with which it has nothing to do. Play framework Morphia plugin ties this up. But now CRUD operations are different when using the plugin which I am using in my case as opposed to when using just Morphia without the plugin.

I using play 1.2.2RC2. and morphia plugin morphia-1.2.1beta6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about Scala, but with Java it is simply

```
user.save();
```

or for validation:

```
user.validateAndSave();
```